Is the quadratic variation process also a martingale?
Given that the sum of two martingales, adapted to the same filtration, is also a martingale (see this ME stack answer), I would posit that the quadratic variation of martingale $M$ is also a martingale, since
$$ \langle M \rangle_t = - (M_t - \langle M \rangle_t) + M_t$$
Am I correct?

\langle and \rangle for QV

The quadratic variation process is non-decreasing, so it is not a martingale (unless it is constant at $0$).
The flaw in your argument is that $M_t - \langle M\rangle_t$ is not a martingale, rather, $M_t^2 - \langle M\rangle_t$ is.  Since $M_t^2$ is not a martingale (again, unless $M_t$ is constant), we can't use the result that the sum of martingales is a martingale in the equation $$ \langle M \rangle_t = -(M_t^2 - \langle M\rangle_t) + M_t^2.$$

Thanks for the reply.  ;)
